Is it possible to pause GPU execution, perform file I/O operations, and then resume execution using the Vulkan API with vkCmdSetEvent?
I am trying to do something with the Vulkan API, but I am not sure if it is possible. Basically, I want to build a command list of draw calls like this:
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 0, 0); // Draw call 1
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 3, 0); // Draw call 2
// STOP the GPU completely
// Do some file I/O operations
// Then continue with more draw calls
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 6, 0); // Draw call 3
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 9, 0); // Draw call 4

I was looking at this example:
https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/API-Samples/events/events.cpp#L131
But I don't fully understand what vkCmdSetEvent really does. There is no callback mechanism. For instance, if I do this:
result = vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

// First set of draw calls (placeholders)
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 0, 0); // Draw call 1
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 3, 0); // Draw call 2

// Set the event
vkCmdSetEvent(commandBuffer, event, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT);

// Wait for the event
vkCmdWaitEvents(
    commandBuffer,
    1, &event,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, // srcStageMask
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, // dstStageMask
    0, NULL,                            // Memory barriers
    0, NULL,                            // Buffer memory barriers
    0, NULL                             // Image memory barriers
);

// Second set of draw calls (placeholders)
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 6, 0); // Draw call 3
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 3, 1, 9, 0); // Draw call 4

result = vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

What does this really do? It will just wait, do nothing, then process more draw calls. I'd need something like this:
vkCmdSetEvent(commandBuffer, callbackDoSomething);

callbackDoSomething() {
    fopen; fread; fclose

    // Done, signal GPU to proceed
}

vkCmdWaitEvents(...);

Can this be done somehow? I am not fully following the vkCmdSetEvent and vkCmdWaitEvents APIs. What are these for exactly? Do they just put halts in the command buffer?
Thank you very much.

I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking, sorry... vkCmd* put stuff in a command buffer, which is executed later, after you submit it (not synchronous). In general, Vulkan is an explicitly asynchronous API, and doesn't hide that from you like OpenGL. Theoretically, you can pass a fence when calling vk...Submit and wait on it, I guess. But what problem would you like to solve with this? How is IO stuff related to what you're doing on the GPU?

The details of that are too long since it is driver work. But I'd need to interrupt the GPU in a middle of execution of command buffer, perform I/O operation (fopen/fread/fclose) then resume the operation. Can it be done with vulkan API?

Short answer, no, this would be out-of-spec. You need to split the command buffer, and wait on the completion fence for the first part, do the callback, and then submit the second part.

Please take a look at my solution below. It does seem to be working correctly with my tests, but very few draw calls. @solidpixel if you have a chance please comment on it. Thank you!

If you view "I only have two seconds until my OS timeout mechanism triggers" as "working correctly" then I don't think I can offer much advice.

TLDR: What you are doing is out-of-spec. It "might work" on a specific device, but you are firmly in the realms of undefined behavior.

I have attached a potential solution below. However, there are a few constraints to consider. On windows I have only 2 to 3 seconds before it triggers a Timeout Detection and Recovery (TDR). This is not an issue since the purpose is solely for debugging, and I only need to write a single DWORD to the file system.
Additionally, I am uncertain if vkCmdWaitEvents will wait until the entire command buffer is executed, as it utilizes VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT. It is unclear whether it will halt after the second draw call in my example.
Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,
// make it unsignaled, GPU will have to wait
vkResetEvent(info.device, event);

execute_begin_command_buffer(info);
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 0, 1, 0, 0);       // some draw calls
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 0, 1, 0, 0);       // some draw calls
vkCmdWaitEvents(info.cmd, 1, &event, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 0, 1, 0, 0);       // other draw calls
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, 0, 1, 0, 0);       // other draw calls
execute_end_command_buffer(info);
vkResetFences(info.device, 1, &fence);

pipe_stage_flags = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
res = vkQueueSubmit(info.graphics_queue, 1, submit_info, fence);
assert(res == VK_SUCCESS);

// write my debug registed information
// I only have two seconds until TDR, but that should be more than enough time to do a trivial I/O operation
FILE *file = fopen("debug_reg_io.txt", "w");
if (file) {
    fputs("0xc0ffebea", file);
    fclose(file);
}

// unblock GPU now
vkSetEvent(info.device, event);
do {
    res = vkWaitForFences(info.device, 1, &fence, VK_TRUE, FENCE_TIMEOUT);
} while (res == VK_TIMEOUT);
assert(res == VK_SUCCESS);

